# function isnt performing every second it only performs once after one second and never again

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

```
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.startBtn');
const pauseBtn = document.querySelector('.pauseBtn');
const ResetBtn = document.querySelector('.resetBtn');
const time = document.querySelector('.time');

let seconds = 0;
let secondsStr = '00';
let minutes = 0;
let minutesStr = '00';
let hours = 0;
let hoursStr = '00';
let timeText = `${hoursStr}:${minutesStr}:${secondsStr}`;
time.textContent = timeText;

const startTimer = setTimeout(addSecond, 1000);

function addSecond() {
    seconds++;
    secondsStr = seconds.toString();
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsStr = `0${secondsStr}`;
    }
    timeText = `${hoursStr}:${minutesStr}:${secondsStr}`;
    time.textContent = timeText;
}
```

```
<div class="stopwatch">
        <div class="time"></div>
        <div class="stopwatchBtns">
            <button class="startBtn stopwatchBtn">Start</button>
            <button class="pauseBtn stopwatchBtn">Pause</button>
            <button class="resetBtn stopwatchBtn">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in short, the startTimer timeout only performs after 1 second and doesnt execute ever again, ive tried using the console to debug this issue but nothing seems to work and i dont know what to do

i tried using a different function and a different timeout but nothing a tried worked

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: @Konrad oh yeah i forgot that existed thats worked now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is a single-shot timer. For a recurring timer, use `setInterval`.